# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline returnStatus null

Tags: java, jenkins

I have created a Scripted pipeline Jenkins job, in one of the stage I need to run a java file example:- java -jar accountrans.jar and I need to return the value to the variable.

```
stage('Account Process')
{    
    sh 'curl --noproxy "*" -X GET https://paraforce.com/artifactory/account/accountrans.jar -o accountrans.jar'    
    def acctval = sh script: "java -jar accountrans.jar . ", returnStatus: true    
    echo "Account Trans Value : " $acctval 
}
```

I am getting error message java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'java.lang.ClassCastException: body return value null is not boolean' on null object

When I ran the jar file from the command line I am able to view the return value.

Please help how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but try curly braces after sh.

```
stage('Account Process')
{    
    sh 'curl --noproxy "*" -X GET https://paraforce.com/artifactory/account/accountrans.jar -o accountrans.jar'    
    def acctval = sh {script: "java -jar accountrans.jar . ", returnStdout: true }   
    echo "Account Trans Value : " $acctval 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your program outputs something to the Stdout. But you are trying to retreive the status code. Instead of `returnStatus` try  `returnStdout`.

```
stage('Account Process')
{    
    sh 'curl --noproxy "*" -X GET https://paraforce.com/artifactory/account/accountrans.jar -o accountrans.jar'    
    def acctval = sh script: "java -jar accountrans.jar . ", returnStdout: true    
    echo "Account Trans Value : " $acctval 
}
```